# "Store" a lot of data

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript and I'm not sure about the best way to store data.
I'll write an example about what I want to obtain:

```
Country1
     Country informations
     Region1
            Region informations
            Place1
                 Place informations
            Place2
                 Place informations
     Region2
            Region informations
            Place1
                 Place informations
            Place2
                 Place informations
Country2
     Country informations
     Region1
            Region informations
            Place1
                 Place informations
            Place2
                 Place informations
     Region2
            Region informations
            Place1
                 Place informations
            Place2
                 Place informations
...
```

Consider "informations" as different values like x, y, name, ecc...
I want to be able to access these properties in an easy way, something like 1-1-2-x

The best solution that came to my mind was to use a 4d array to store "place informations", a 3d one to store "Region informations" and a matrix to store "country informations"

Do you think this is the best solution? I hope my explanation is understandable, thanks.

Comment: Where do you want to store it? DB, File?

Comment: Are you using any servers-de code? e.g. C# ?

Comment: I'm using just javascript, I want to keep everything client-side

Comment: Have you considered using a multi-dimensional array?

Comment: That's what I meant with 3d and 4d array, sorry if I haven't used the correct terms

Comment: @Bonfi Refresh the page and check the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [JSON](http://www.json.org/) is what you're after.

Example:

```
var data = {
    countries : [
       {
           name: 'country1',
           regions: [
               {
                   name: 'region1',
                   places: [
                       {
                           name: 'place1'
                       }
                   ]
               }
           ]
       }
    ]
};
```

Here we have an array of countries. Each country can have an array of regions. Each region, an array of places.

You can consume this by indexes:

```
var place = data.contries[0].regions[0].places[0].name;
```

Or you can write custom methods to access by name:

```
var data = {
    getCountry : function(name) {
        var len = this.countries.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (name === this.countries[i].name)
                return this.countries[i];
        }
        return null;
    },
    countries : [
       {
           getRegion : function(name) {
               var len = this.regions.length;
               for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                   if (name === this.regions[i].name)
                       return this.regions[i];
               }
               return null;
           },
           name: 'country1',
           regions: [
               {
                   name: 'region1',
                   places: [
                       {
                           name: 'place1'
                       }
                   ]
               }
           ]
       }
    ]
};
```

Usage:

```
var region = data.getCountry('county1').getRegion('region1');
```

Verbose data example:

```
var data = {
    countries : [
       {
           name: 'country1',
           regions: [
               {
                   name: 'region1',
                   places: [
                       {
                           name: 'place1'
                       },
                       {
                           name: 'place2'
                       }
                   ]
               },
               {
                   name: 'region2',
                   places: [
                       {
                           name: 'place3'
                       },
                       {
                           name: 'place4'
                       }
                   ]
               }
           ]
       },
       {
           name: 'country2',
           regions: [
               {
                   name: 'region3',
                   places: [
                       {
                           name: 'place5'
                       },
                       {
                           name: 'place6'
                       }
                   ]
               },
               {
                   name: 'region4',
                   places: [
                       {
                           name: 'place7'
                       },
                       {
                           name: 'place8'
                       }
                   ]
               }
           ]
       }
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create [JSON](http://www.json.org/js.html) objects for your data and store in a [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/).  There's some [documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/insert.html) here how to store and retrieve the data.

There's an [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299886.aspx) here for further understanding, so you can see how to create the JSON object(s), it will then be up to you how you want to store them.

Answer (score 0):

Storing this amount of data in client-side without Ajax requests is not suggested. However what will I do at this moment is this:

```
var data= new Array()

data["US"] = new Array();
data["US"]["Info"] = "United Stats Information...";
data["US"]["Arizona"] = new Array();
data["US"]["Arizona"]["Info"] = "Region Info...";
data["US"]["Arizona"]["placeA"] = "PlaceA Info!";
data["US"]["Arizona"]["placeB"] = "PlaceB Info!";
```

Comment: I think Array does not support to store data by key, probably it stores the data using properties as same as JSON.

Comment: This will make a JavaScript object, we don't have associative arrays in JavaScript.